# C# Method called with a Switch statement - having troubles

Tags: c#

I am new at programming and I'm trying to understand why the methods call inside a switch statement is not working. Basically I have a main menu and a submenu. Whem I press the Animal submenu , the switch statement is meant to call the methods for a CRUD (insert new, visualize by Id, update, etc) but none of these options are working. Is the method call/structure correct?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace menu_clinica_veterinaria
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int id = 1;
        enum animalHeader { id, name, client_name, type_animal };
        enum clientHeader { id, name, client_surname, adrress };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] animal = new string[20, 4];
            string[,] client = new string[20, 6];

            do { MenuOptions(animal); } while (true);
        }

        static void MenuOptions(string[,] animal)
        {
            int userChoice;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nChoose one of the following options:\n");

                Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Animals");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] Clients");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Quit application\n");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userChoice) || userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 2);

            Console.Clear();

            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    menuAnimal(animal);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //menuClient(client);
                    break;

                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again!!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void menuAnimal(string[,] animal)
        {
            int optAnimal;

            while (true)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInsert one of the following options:\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Insert animal");
                    Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] See animal");
                    Console.WriteLine("[ 3 ] Alter animal");
                    Console.WriteLine("[ 4 ] Erase animal");
                    Console.WriteLine("[ 5 ] List animals");
                    Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Return to main menu\n");
                } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out optAnimal) || optAnimal < 0 || optAnimal > 5);

                Console.Clear();
                bool goBack = false;

                switch (optAnimal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        insertData(animal);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        visualizeByid(animal);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        updateById(animal);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        deleteByid(animal);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        listData(animal);
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        goBack = true;
                        break;
                }

                if (goBack) return;
            }
        }

        static void mainMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void menuReturn(string[,] animal)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            do { menuAnimal(animal); } while (true);
        }

        static int generateId()
        {
            return id++;
        }

        static int getInsertIndex(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[j, 0])) return j;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        static void insertData(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int id = generateId();
            int n = getInsertIndex(matrix);

            matrix[n, 0] = Convert.ToString(id);

            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}: ");
                    matrix[n, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[n, j]));
            }
        }

        static int searchId(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int choosenId, index = -1;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Insert ID to continue: ");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choosenId));

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(choosenId) == matrix[i, 0])
                {
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        static void visualizeByid(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);

            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Wrong Id"); }
        }

        static void updateById(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);

            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}:  ");
                        matrix[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Id does not exist"); }
        }

        static void deleteByid(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);

            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Id does not exist"); }
        }

        static void listData(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"\t{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attached a debugger (visual studio) and stepped though the code?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It´s hard to scan your entire code.

Comment: I would try to trim that code down to the relevant sections. Many people will just move on instead of trying to spend so much time reading the entire document to and trying to filter out all the extra irrelevant stuff.

Comment: I'd suggest you have a read though [Getting Started with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour). If you actually debug this code I'd imagine you'll find your issue much easier to figure out.

Comment: I'm really sorry if the code is huge but since it is a stwich method that calls another switch methods I tought there were somethig wrong, when I press 1 at the main menu it goes to the Submenu however nome of the CRUD options are working.

Comment: your while loop doesn't open at the top?

Comment: @Ricardo I complied your basic SWITCH code and its working. I mean all the methods and cases are reachable and executed. Where is exact issue is?

Comment: It works for me. Everything. I can add an animal, see an animal. I just copy and pasted all that code into Visual Studio and it worked fine. I added `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of `visualizeById` so that it just doesn't exit and show you nothing. Maybe thats what you think is wrong. It immediately goes back to the menu after performing an action because you have no `Console.ReadKey` to make it wait long enough for you to actually *see* the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nifty little program for what it is.

However, you can't see an animal because:

**searchId**

```
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   if (Convert.ToString(choosenId) == matrix[i, 0])
   {
      index = i;
      // Though it's not the problem you could break here
      // you could also just return from here
      break;
   }
}
```

Also, you'll need to `Console.ReadKey()` somewhere as your menu refreshes and overwrites the see animal routine.

**menuAnimal**

```
visualizeByid(animal);

// if you don't do something like this as the menu refreshes the animal away
Console.ReadKey();
```

The only other thing I'd suggest is to use lists and well-typed classes, instead of multidimensional arrays of strings; they are easier to work with, and you can use Linq.

### Update

In regards to comments, given this:

```
private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);
```

You could do something like this:

```
static void updateById<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
   int pos = searchId(matrix);
   if (pos != -1)
   {
      for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
         {
            Console.Write($"Insert {GetHeader<T>(j)}:  ");
            ...
```

Usage:

```
updateById<animalHeader>(animal);
```

Basically this is some generics to reuse the `updateById` method and using your HeaderType.

Comment: yes,I got now why it wasn't working, thanks! What about the Enum I'm using as a header to the CRUD methods, I know I have to use them as parameters and so on. The only problem I see is on the:                    Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}: "); How  do I create a method that replaces the Enum for each Submenu? for clients for ex, or another statements on the switch?

Comment: @Ricardo you could replace `"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}: "` with `"Insert {(animalHeader)j)}: "`

Comment: but still I want to the same methods (insertdata,deletedata,updatedata) in every submenu if I go with this animalHeader it will apply the same option to all of them, I have a clientHeader and I'm trying to use it on the submenu of clients though the code isn't there .

Comment: @Ricardo i see what you are asking, 2 secs

Comment: yes THeGeneral I checked and it's perfect, thanks a lot. I got your answer as correct.

Answer (score -2):

Your program working Fine. You are using Console.Clear(). It will clear the screen which is displayed previously on the screen. Remove Console.Clear() in the program or Add Console.ReadKey() immediately after Switch block. I think it will work fine.